# while printing some statements in console without main function using static block

Tags: java, static

```
public class Riwo{

    static {
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.exit(0);
    }


}
```

---

Err

```
or: Main method not found in class saky.Riwo, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an exception for classes that extend `javafx.application.Application` - you don't need to define the `main` method for them.

> The java command can be used to launch a JavaFX application by loading a class that either **has a `main()` method or that extends the `javafx.application.Application`**. In the latter case, the launcher constructs an instance of the Application class, calls its `init()` method, and then calls the `start(javafx.stage.Stage)` method.

Otherwise, in order to start a Java application, the `main` has to be defined.

Static blocks are executed when their class is being loaded into the JVM. For a class to be loaded, there should be a trigger/launcher somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the main method for the class to be compiled and executed for the JVM.
You can use this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: but by using  static block and system.exit(0) we can print statement in console without using main method